# Google Cloud Endpoints target to Internal IP of VM Instance (Compute Engine)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Is it possible to configure Endpoints to target to an Internal IP of Compute Engine VM Instance?

I followed the Echo API java example and expose the service with Endpoints. Everything works great. I can successfully send a request to FQDN (echo-api.endpoints.`[PROJECT_ID]`.cloud.goog).

But I don't want to leave an External IP in this VM instance. Because I still can send a request directly to the External IP bypassing the Endpoints.

When I try to set the External IP to None on this VM Instance, and setting the `target` value to Internal IP in `openapi.yaml`, my Echo service is not accessible with Endpoints DNS anymore.

So, Is it possible to target a Endpoint API to an Internal IP of a VM Instance of Compute Engine?

thanks!

Answer (score -1):

A similar question was answered in the Google Cloud Endpoints group:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-cloud-endpoints/tL9LN9OojHs/3GySDuECAgAJ